# C++ Audio Only Playing Through One Speaker

Tags: c++, audio, openal

I have the 'ding.wav' file from the Windows System folder and am trying to get it to play using C++ and OpenAL. My problem is that the following code only makes it play through one headphone / speaker. Can anybody identify the problem? The code works fine when I put it in a new project but I cannot understand why.

```
    alDevice = alcOpenDevice(alcGetString(NULL, ALC_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER));
    alContext = alcCreateContext(alDevice, NULL);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(alContext);

    alListener3f(AL_POSITION, 0.0f, 0, 1.0f);
    alListener3f(AL_VELOCITY, 0, 0, 0);
    ALfloat listenerOri[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
    alListenerfv(AL_ORIENTATION,listenerOri);

    alGenSources((ALuint)1, &alSource);
    alSourcef(alSource, AL_PITCH, 1);
    alSourcef(alSource, AL_GAIN, 1);
    alSource3f(alSource, AL_POSITION, 0, 0, 0);
    alSource3f(alSource, AL_VELOCITY, 0, 0, 0);
    alSourcei(alSource, AL_LOOPING, AL_FALSE);

    alGenBuffers(1, &alBuffer);
    alutLoadWAVFile("C:/ding.wav", &format, &data, &size, &freq, &loop);
    alBufferData(alBuffer, format, data, size, freq);
    alSourcei(alSource, AL_BUFFER, alBuffer);
    alSourcePlay(alSource);
    alGetSourcei(alSource, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &source_state);
    while (source_state == AL_PLAYING) {
        alGetSourcei(alSource, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &source_state);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"the code works fine when I put it in a new project"_?

Comment: When I place this code in a fresh 'main.c' file and compile it linking only to OpenAL, it works perfectly and sound is played through both speakers.

Comment: So, essentially that's exactly what you have posted here.  You're saying that if we take the code as-is, and compile and link it ourselves, there will be no problem.  What is the context of the program where it _isn't_ working?  What is different?  You haven't described the difference.